# Why not go to the second transaction when I press the button

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-volley

I made an application to check if the user name and password are correct or not and if they are true, it goes to the interface where the program displays the user data, but when building the application there is no error but when pressing the login button nothing happens and get this result in the terminal

I want to receive more than one variable from mysql database and I use php to print json and library volley

```
V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: HiTouch on notch display, height corret:90
I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@55e6860,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@73fe119
    initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@6e475d5,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@73fe119
    initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@614e378,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@73fe119
    initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@53392b6,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@73fe119
    initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/ViewRootImpl: jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x71993e2010 disconnect failed
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for id_card
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
        at com.androidigniter.loginandregistration.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:134)
        at com.androidigniter.loginandregistration.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:126)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
V/InputMethodManager: Reporting focus gain, without startInput
```

**session handler class**

```
package com.androidigniter.loginandregistration;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by AndroidIgniter on 23 Mar 2019 020.
 */

public class SessionHandler {
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserSession";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_EXPIRES = "expires";
    private static final String KEY_FULL_NAME = "full_name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_COUNTRY = "country";
    private static final String KEY_ID_CARD= "id_card";
    private static final String KEY_EMPTY = "";
    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    public SessionHandler(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Logs in the user by saving user details and setting session
     *
     * @param email
     * @param username
     * @param fullName
     * @param country
     * @param id_card
     *
     *
     */
    public void loginUser( String username, String fullName, String email , String country , String id_card) {
        mEditor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_FULL_NAME, fullName);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_ID_CARD, id_card);
       // mEditor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, card_id);
        Date date = new Date();

        //Set user session for next 7 days
        long millis = date.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        mEditor.putLong(KEY_EXPIRES, millis);
        mEditor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether user is logged in
     *
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        Date currentDate = new Date();

        long millis = mPreferences.getLong(KEY_EXPIRES, 0);

        /* If shared preferences does not have a value
         then user is not logged in
         */
        if (millis == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        Date expiryDate = new Date(millis);

        /* Check if session is expired by comparing
        current date and Session expiry date
        */
        return currentDate.before(expiryDate);
    }

    /**
     * Fetches and returns user details
     *
     * @return user details
     */
    public User getUserDetails() {
        //Check if user is logged in first
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            return null;
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(mPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, KEY_EMPTY));
        user.setFullName(mPreferences.getString(KEY_FULL_NAME, KEY_EMPTY));
        user.setEmail(mPreferences.getString(KEY_EMAIL, KEY_EMPTY));
        user.setCountry(mPreferences.getString(KEY_COUNTRY, KEY_EMPTY));
       user.setEmail(mPreferences.getString(KEY_ID_CARD, KEY_EMPTY));
        user.setSessionExpiryDate(new Date(mPreferences.getLong(KEY_EXPIRES, 0)));

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Logs out user by clearing the session
     */
    public void logoutUser(){
        mEditor.clear();
        mEditor.commit();
    }

}
```

**login class**

```
package com.androidigniter.loginandregistration;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String KEY_FULL_NAME = "full_name";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String KEY_COUNTRY = "country";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_ID_CARD= "id_card";
    private static final String KEY_EMPTY = "";


    private EditText etUsername;
    private EditText etPassword;


    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String country;
    private String id_card;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String login_url = "http://192.168.1.101/member/login.php";
    private SessionHandler session;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        session = new SessionHandler(getApplicationContext());

        if(session.isLoggedIn()){
            loadDashboard();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etLoginUsername);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etLoginPassword);

        Button register = findViewById(R.id.btnLoginRegister);
        Button login = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        //Launch Registration sc-حححreen when Register Button is clicked
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Retrieve the data entered in the edit texts
                username = etUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (validateInputs()) {
                    login();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Launch Dashboard Activity on Successful Login
     */
    private void loadDashboard() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }

    /**
     * Display Progress bar while Logging in
     */

    private void displayLoader() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging In.. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    private void login() {
        displayLoader();
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try {
            //Populate the request parameters
            request.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            request.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            request.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            request.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
            request.put(KEY_ID_CARD, id_card);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, login_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            //Check if user got logged in successfully

                            if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                                session.loginUser(username,email,response.getString(KEY_EMAIL),response.getString(KEY_COUNTRY),response.getString(KEY_ID_CARD));



                                //session.loginUser(username,response.getString(KEY_CARD_ID));
                              // session.loginUser(username,response.getString(KEY_ID_CON));
                                loadDashboard();

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                        //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
    }

    /**
     * Validates inputs and shows error if any
     * @return
     */
    private boolean validateInputs() {
        if(KEY_EMPTY.equals(username)){
            etUsername.setError("Username cannot be empty");
            etUsername.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        if(KEY_EMPTY.equals(password)){
            etPassword.setError("Password cannot be empty");
            etPassword.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @kvra13. Can you please post the JSONObject response that you get? From the exception stack trace, it looks like the id_card is not present in the response.